# Comapring two object does not invoke CompareTo method

Tags: c#, compareto

My class is implementing IComparable interface as follows.

```
public class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass>
    {
        public SomeEnum?      Field1            { get; set; }
        public int?           Field2            { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(MyClass other)
        {
            if (this.Field1 == other.Field1 && this.Field2 == other.Field2)
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
        }
    }
```

Somewhere else in the code I am comparing two instance of this class as follows

```
if ( MyClassInstance1 != MyClassInstance2 )
```

At this point, I don't see CompareTo invoked. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: BTW, your implementation is wrong.  See the documentation.

Comment: It also looks like you might have your 0 and 1 backwards.

Comment: may be typo, was trying to make up an example on fly to put my question out there. love the SO cuz I got answer even with those typos :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CompareTo()` is a regular method, and can be called like any other regular method.

It sounds like you actually want to overload the `==` and `!=` operators (and override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( MyClassInstance1.CompareTo(MyClassInstance2) ==1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently checking if `MyClassInstance1` is a different object from `MyClassInstance2`. Because they are objects, each one is unique. and your if statement will always be true. You will want to call your `CompareTo` method:

```
if (MyClassInstance1.CompareTo(MyClassInstance2) != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`IComparable<T>` is used for sorting, not for equality.

The `!=` and `==` operators don't invoke this, they invoke the `Equals()` method.

If they invoked `CompareTo()` you'd get a `StackOverflowException` as it uses `!=` and `==`.